# Where is the temporary directory defined in the code?

Tags: 8, configuration

I wonder where the tmp dir is set in the code of Drupal 8. Indeed the upload_tmp_dir value is not set in the php.ini and I have no access to change it.

Where in the code the value is defined and change it?

Comment: Do you have any errors on `admin/reports/status` ?

Answer (score 3):

The logic for finding the proper OS temp directory is in `FileSystem::getOsTemporaryDirectory`.  This will try to use `upload_tmp_dir`, otherwise default back to an OS value, like `/tmp`.

This get used in `file_directory_temp()`.  If you read this function, you will see that the config value gets read first, and then it will try to get the OS default.

Personally, I set the filesystem paths in my settings.local.php file, so I can have a different value per environment, eg

```
$config['system.file']['path']['temporary'] = '/var/www/staging/tmp';
```

You also need to ensure that the file is writable by the webserver.  [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924) is the canonical reference on this, but in short something like

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/staging/tmp
sudo find /var/www/staging/tmp -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/staging/tmp -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the setting in /admin/config/media/file-system.
If you need that in php, you can use code like

```
Drupal::configFactory()->get('system.file');
```

The correct config for your tmp dir is `system.file.path.temporary`. Check it in the UI with config-sync of simple config "system.file". Check `class FileUploadResource` for an example.

Comment: To clarify this: It's not set in "code", it's a configuration of your Drupal System.

Comment: I have tried to modify the value of temporary dir with the UI in /admin/config/media/file-system but it doesn't work it's for that i need to change it in the code of drupal 8, it is possible ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You need an editable config like so: \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('user.settings')
      ->set('notify.status_activated', FALSE)
      ->save();

Comment: Ok thanks but where i put this line of code ? thanks in advance

Comment: i can change the value of temporary directory in UI /admin/config/media/file-system the value change but when i upload files i have an error like : "your tmp dir is not defined"

Comment: That is a problem with your server configuration

Comment: something to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to hack the core. Which is evil. You simply can set another temporary directory on https://example.com/admin/config/media/file-system.

[image]

---

Via Drush.

```
$ drush -y config:set system.file path.temporary /Users/norman/Sites/temp
```

---

Alternatively but also quite evil is overriding PHP config from your settings.php. But note that some server setups may block PHP script files containing `ini_set()` calls, resulting in a WSOD.

`ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', '/tmp');`

Comment: When i try to change temporary folder by UI at  admin/config/media/file-system. this doesn't work, i dont know why .. this is the problem :/ The upload_tmp_dir is not defined and not accessible and init_set dont work beacause this variable cant be change by init_set

Comment: That is a problem with your server configuration

Comment: something to do ?